# RegEx for getting value inside Json String

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var string = "[{"name":"person1", "city": "city1"},
               {"name":"person2", "city":"city1"},
               {"name":"person3", "city": "city1"}]"
```

How to getting value of string var with regex ?

result  => `["person1", "person2", "person3"]`

Comment: You can do it with `JSON.parse()` you dont want that?

Comment: are you aware of `JSON.parse()` which will convert your json into object notation. Then you can access values of the object with ease. Or is there a specific reason you are choosing regex ?

Comment: `JSON.parse` only works on valid json strings, the string posted above is invalid

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy you right, i can do it with `JSON.parse` , but i dont know which are the fastest between iterate lopp and regex if the deal with big data, i think i need to benchmark

Answer (score 1):

**RegEx for getting value inside Json String**

I had to make your variable string a `valid string` for this demo. And here is the code that would help you get your desired results.

Regex used: `/{"name":"(.*?)"/g` with capturing group `(.*?)` to extract only the required data.

```js
function getMatches(string, regex, index) {
  index || (index = 1); // default to the first capturing group
  var matches = [];
  var match;
  while (match = regex.exec(string)) {
    matches.push(match[index]);
  }
  return matches;
}


var string = '[{"name":"person1", "city": "city1"},{"name":"person2", "city":"city1"},{"name":"person3", "city": "city1"}]';

var matches = getMatches(string, /{"name":"(.*?)"/g, 1);

// Log results
document.write(JSON.stringify(matches))
```

Comment: which are the fastest between iterate lopp and regex if the deal with big data ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your initial string into valid JSON notation.
Then, you'll be able to easily get an array of persons using `JSON.parse` and `Array.map` functions:

```
var string = '[{"name":"person1", "city": "city1"},{"name":"person2", "city":"city1"},{"name":"person3", "city": "city1"}]';

var persons = JSON.parse(string).map(function(v){ return v['name']; });
console.log(persons);  // ["person1", "person2", "person3"]
```

Comment: which are the fastest between iterate lopp and regex if the deal with big data ?

Comment: iterating through the loop will definitely go faster.(but results may differ among different browsers)

Comment: It will also depend on how "big" is your data and the complexity of your regex

Answer (score 0):

You probably donot even need RegEx for that. You could just use the below code.

```
var objects = JSON.parse(string); //Parse your string to JS object
var result = [];
objects.forEach(function(item,index,arr) //Iterate add to result array
{
   result.push(item.name); 
});
```

Comment: which are the fastest between iterate lopp and regex if the deal with big data ?

Comment: As far as I know, Looping over objects give you better performance than Regex in js. But anyway both correspond to O(n).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JSON.parse** and then **map** to get names:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(string);
var names = obj.map(function(o) {
    return o.name;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xrzeg7h2/